# Why the growth direction of heap address become opposite when allocating larger space?

Tags: c++, c, memory, operating-system

I was doing some experiments on the heap address growth, and something interesting happened.
(OS: CentOS, )

But I don't understand, why this happened? Thanks!

This is what I did first:

```
double *ptr[1000];
for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){
    ptr[i] = new double[**10000**];
    cout << ptr[i] << endl;
}
```

The output is incremental(for the last few lines):

```
....
....
0x2481be0
0x2495470
0x24a8d00
0x24bc590
0x24cfe20
0x24e36b0
0x24f6f40
0x250a7d0
0x251e060
```

Then I changed 10000 to 20000:

```
double *ptr[1000];
for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){
    ptr[i] = new double[**20000**];
    cout << ptr[i] << endl;
}
```

The address became more like the address of stack space(and decremental):

```
....
....
0x7f69c4d8a010
0x7f69c4d62010
0x7f69c4d3a010
0x7f69c4d12010
0x7f69c4cea010
0x7f69c4cc2010
0x7f69c4c9a010
0x7f69c4c72010
0x7f69c4c4a010
0x7f69c4c22010
0x7f69c4bfa010
0x7f69c4bd2010
0x7f69c4baa010
0x7f69c4b82010
```

Answer (score 7):

Different environments/implementations allocate memory using different strategies, so there is no one correct rule. However, a common pattern is to use different allocation strategies for small objects vs. large objects.

Often, a runtime will have multiple heaps for objects of different sizes, which are optimized for different usage patterns. For example, small objects tend to be allocated often and deleted quickly, while large objects tend to be created rarely and have a long life.

If you use a single heap for everything, then a few small objects will be quickly peppered throughout your memory space, leaving lots of medium sized blocks available but few or no large blocks needed for larger objects. This is referred to as memory fragmentation, and can cause your allocation to fail even if nominally your app has tons of memory available.

Another reason to use different heaps is to use a different usage tracking method for different object sizes. For example, an implementation might request a new memory block from the OS for large objects, and for small objects, use a few smaller OS memory blocks with sub-allocations handled by the C runtime heap manager. Memory usage tracking mechanisms that are very effective for large objects can be very expensive for smaller ones because the memory used for tracking usage becomes a significant fraction of the actual memory used by each object.

In your case, my guess is that the runtime is allocating small objects at the beginning of the memory space, bottom-up, and larger ones near the end, top-down, to avoid fragmentation.

Answer (score 4):

You're not going to get a great answer here, because the new function can choose any method it wants to allocate memory.  My guess would be that the algorithm here broke the pool into small and large allocation pools, and the big allocation pool grows downward so they can meet in the middle (so as to not waste any space).

Answer (score 0):

On UNIX, allocators use sbrk(2) and mmap(2) to get memory from the OS.  The addresses returned by sbrk are well defined, but the addresses from mmap are "whatever is available".  On Windows, allocators use VirtualAlloc() which is kind of like mmap.

Answer (score 0):

Implementations are free to have hybrids of different allocation schemes.  In C++, it's normal for there to be thousands - even millions - of relatively small objects, so it can make sense for the library's memory allocation routines to make sure they pack well and are very lightweight.  Your allocations for 10000 doubles do that: they're 80016 bytes apart - 80000 for 10000 8 byte variables and just 16 bytes padding.  Node specifically that the size has no relationship to powers of two, whereas when allocation 20000 doubles they're decrementing by 163840 bytes each time... weirdly, exactly 10 * 2^14.  That suggests to me that the former allocations are being satisfied from one heap designed to support efficient small-object allocation by the C++ allocation `new` function, while the latter has crossed a theshold and is probably being sent to `malloc` for memory coming from a distinct heap, with much more waste.

Answer (score 0):

You were lucky in the sense that the sizes of 10000 doubles and 20000 doubles happen to lie on the opposite sides of a critical thresholds called MMAP_THRESHOLD.

MMAP_THRESHOLD is 128KB by default. So, 80KB (i.e., 10000 doubles) mem alloc requests are serviced over heap, and whereas 160KB (20000 doubles) mem alloc requests are serviced by anonymous memory mapping (through mmap sys call). (Note that using mem mapping for large mem alloc may incur additional penalties due to its different underlying mem alloc handling mechanism. You may want to tune MMAP_THRESHOLD for optimal performance of your apps.)

In [Linux Man for malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc):

> Normally, malloc() allocates memory from the heap, and adjusts the size of the heap as required, using sbrk(2). When allocating blocks of memory larger than MMAP_THRESHOLD bytes, the glibc malloc() implementation allocates the memory as a private anonymous mapping using mmap(2). MMAP_THRESHOLD is 128 kB by default, but is adjustable using mallopt(3). Allocations performed using mmap(2) are unaffected by the RLIMIT_DATA resource limit (see getrlimit(2)).